# html2canvas - Not supporting CSS transform property

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I have a webpage, I am using html2canvas to print it. My web page has UI grid and its header text needs to rotate so I'm using transform and rotate CSS property. They rotate accordingly in browser but When I print there rotation distort and image is looking too bad.

Please Find my below code

CSS:

```
/* ui-grid cell class starts */
    .headerRotatedV{
        writing-mode: tb-rl;
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    }
    report.js:

    var colDefRetByDealerS8 = [
            {
                field: 'salesRank',
                fieldName: 'Sales Rank',
                width: '2%',
                cellTemplate: '<div></div>',
                headerCellTemplate: "<div><a class='headerRotatedV'>{{col.displayName}}</a></div>",
            },
            {
                field: 'dealerName',
                fieldName: 'Dealership',
                width: '10%',
                cellTemplate: '<div></div>'
            },
            {
                field: 'Region',
                fieldName: 'Today',
                width: '2%',
                cellTemplate: '<div></div>',
                headerCellTemplate: "<div><a class='headerRotatedV'>{{col.displayName}}</a></div>",

            },
            {
                field: 'mdl_vsd',
                displayName: 'Vehicle Model',
                width: '2%',
                cellTemplate: '<div></div>',
                headerCellTemplate: "<div><p class='headerRotatedV'>{{col.displayName}}</p></div>",

            }
    ]

  HTML:  

    <div class="ng-scope"><a class="headerRotatedV ng-binding">Saless Rank</a></div>
    <div class="ng-scope"><a>Dealer name</a></div>
    <div class="ng-scope"><a class="headerRotatedV ng-binding">Region</a></div>
    <div class="ng-scope"><a class="headerRotatedV ng-binding">Vehicle Model</a></div>
```

I have tried using -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);

Can anyone kindly provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: @BadHorsie Please find the edited code snippets

Comment: I think you're better off opening an issue on the [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) github repository.

Comment: @macro-a thank you :-) :-)